# 301 redirect .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

How do I 301 redirect, for example: a subdirectory `/Blog/` to `/blog/` with .htaccess?

Answer (score 9):

```
Redirect 301 /Blog /blog
```

Or use something like http://www.htaccessredirect.net/index.php

Answer (score 3):

The way that immediately comes to mind:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /path/to/your/web/app
RewriteRule ^Blog$ blog [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Blog/(.*)$ blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There are probably much better ways than mod_rewrite, and I'm not 100% sure that the external redirects will work as they should -- you may need the full URL -- but there you go.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest .htaccess solution, place it in /.htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /Blog /blog
```

But it's really limited.  If you want to catch every possible CaSe-wise misspelling, and also forward any other path info (such as /Blog/foo/bar.html), use this instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[Bb][Ll][Oo][Gg](?<!blog)(/.*)?$ /blog$1
```

For more options, there are [full .htaccess generators](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/) available.

Or you can use [ModRewrite-based rules](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) for maximum flexibility, but it's probably overkill.

Comment: Your second example will also match `/blog` at any position.

Comment: Very correct - I rushed to hit the Add Answer too quickly.  Thanks for pointing it out!  The REGEX is fixed now.

Comment: Yes indeed this one is way better althouth there alway the famous:

"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. "