# How can I redirect via htaccess all images of a folder to a static page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect via htaccess all images of a sub folder to my home page. How can I do this?

Example:
http://www.volamondo.it/images/132.jpg --> http://www.volamondo.it/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [301 redirect .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037467/301-redirect-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^images/.* / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I invite you to accept this answer if you want to close this question. [How does accepting an answer work ?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)