# How to redirect main page to url with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

How can I do this redirect via htaccess:
http://example.com -> htpp://example.com?myparam=123

Comment: Possible duplicate of [301 redirect .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037467/301-redirect-htaccess)

Comment: Other useful links: [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9153262/1218980), [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and “pretty links” explained](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772/1218980).

Answer (score 0):

You can say that if query string is empty (RewriteCond line) and requested url is / then redirect user to page with that param, if you want to redirect all pages not just root, then you will change RewriteRule to .* for example

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /?myparam=123 [L,NC,R=301]
```