# Redirect a specific single web page from one domain to a specific web page under another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How do I get the following redirect to work?

The old address contains URL parameters:

```
olddomain.com/Index.asp?CategoryID=2379&ArticleID=6592
```

And needed to redirect to a regular URL under the new domain:

```
newdomain.com/example-page
```

Can I do it via **mod_rewrite on** on my .htaccess file? what is the correct command for this redirection?

I will need to do that for each page under the old domain (the target URL under the new domain will be different for each page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [301 redirect .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037467/301-redirect-htaccess)

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Actually nothing, the only solution I found was to redirect the entire domain to the new domain, without redirecting each page to it's target.